# Why does not Serializable interface require to implement readObject() and writeObject()

Tags: java, serialization

Why is `Serializable` only marker interface and does not require by contract implementing `readObject()` and `writeObject()`. Wouldn't it make more sense?

Comment: That is just the way it is designed.  Serialized is only a marker interface.

Comment: And it was kept that way for backwards compatability.

Comment: It can be a potential security risk for certain data if you mark it as `Serializable` Basically allowing for this classes data to be sent and received by the network.

Comment: Duplicate of [need of Serializable interface in java? As there are no methods in the interface. and how does it maintain state of an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033564/need-of-serializable-interface-in-java-as-there-are-no-methods-in-the-interface), and many others.

Answer (score 2):

The serialization mechanism is able to serialize an object without any `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods. But it requires you to specify it objects can or can't be serialized. Some objects hold data, that it makes sense to serialize. Some others don't. For example, serializing a String makes sense, but serializing a Socket or a database Connection doesn't.
So you simply mark which objects may be serialized by making their class implement the Serializable interface.

If you want more control over the way the state of the object is serialized and deserialized, then you can use these two methods.

Comment: But wouldn't it be less error prone to require at least empty implementation of these methods than to risk that programmer makes error when adding `read/writeObject` like forgetting about private access modifier or something which is not enforced by compiler and which fails silently during runtime? Can incentive behind this be to not have these methods exposed via object api which would have same safety issues?

Comment: The problem is that interfaces force the class to define public methods. They can't force classes to define private ones. And these methods shouldn't be public. Unit tests should be used anyway if those methods are important.