# What is marker interface?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of marker interfaces in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995198/what-is-the-use-of-marker-interfaces-in-java)

What is the use of extending marker interface.

Comment: See [What is the use of marker interfaces in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995198/what-is-the-use-of-marker-interfaces-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

A marker interface is exactly that: A means of marking that a class is or does certain things, even if those things are not expressed as actual methods. Marker interfaces date from very early on; these days while you might use one, you might also look at using annotations instead.

Comment: As a matter of *opinion*, I find marker interfaces a bit of a blunt instrument, and prefer other options. I think I've only ever ended up writing two marker interfaces, in ~12 years of (light) Java development.

Answer (score 4):

It is an interface with no methods. It is just used to "mark" Java classes which support a certain functionality like [Serializable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and [Cloneable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

Answer (score 2):

a marker interface is used to add additional information to an object (see for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern). I dont know what you mean with extending, but a object implements a marker interface.

for example the serializable interface in java:

> A class implements this interface to
>   indicate that its non-transient data
>   members can be written to an
>   ObjectOutputStream

Answer (score 1):

Marker interface are having no methods and they just use to identify the liablity of a class at run time, as your class suppose to have implemented B iterface and then at any point u can check instance of your class pertaining to that interface. U can do whatever you want.