# What are the marker types for assemblies in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, types, automapper, .net-assembly

What are the marker types for assemblies in .NET?

I am learning the AutoMapper through the tutorials and I come across the concept of the `marker types for assemblies` over [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html):

```
// Or marker types for assemblies:
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.AddMaps(new [] {
        typeof(HomeController),
        typeof(Entity)
    });
);
```

While searching for the answer to my question I come over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943142/what-are-marker-interfaces) SO question. But I was not able to find the answer there.

Comment: From the doc, they just look like types which happen to appear in the assemblies of interest. AutoMapper will just call `Type.Assembly` to get the assemblies.

Comment: It's nothing special, it just means you are indicating to Automapper that you are interested in the assemblies containing those types.  You are "marking" them for Automapper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess, that in scope of `AutoMapper` and your sample

```cs
// Or marker types for assemblies:
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.AddMaps(new [] {
        typeof(HomeController),
        typeof(Entity)
    });
);
```

it means any type from the particular assembly, which is used to "mark" the assembly for scanning for mapping profiles. Assemblies containing `HomeController` and `Entity` types will be scanned for getting a types inheriting from `Profile` for mapper configuration

> AutoMapper will scan the designated assemblies for classes inheriting
>   from Profile and add them to the configuration