# Is there any use of interface(in Java) other than standardizing the expectation?

Tags: java, interface

I am new to java and learning interfaces. I did not understand the use of interfaces other than just standardizing the expectation.

If there is any other uses please help me to understand that.

Comment: Can you clarify "standardizing the expectation"? All the answers so far could be seen as examples for standardized expectations (functionality markers, implementation contracts, grouping of similar classes).

Comment: I don't understand why we're voting to close this.  The question may be somewhat vague, but it's a legitimate question and I think we all know what the OP is saying.

Comment: @jagdeep Can you be a little more specific about what you already understand about interfaces?  "standardizing the expectation" *is* pretty vague.

Comment: "Standardizing the expectations": means as per I have read till now  is kind of contract that explains if particular interface is implemented to a class than that means few expected functions methods would be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces have a few good uses:

***Polymorphism***

They allow you to treat several different, but similar, objects in the same way.  For example:

```
public interface Flyer {
  public void fly();
}   

public class Bird implements Flyer {
  @Override
  public void fly() {
    System.out.println("I'm flying");
  }   
}   

public class Airplane implements Flyer {
  @Override
  public void fly() {
    System.out.println("I'm inanimate and flying");
  }   
}   

// then you can have a method like so:
public void makeFly(Flyer flyer) {
  flyer.fly();
} 

// or make a list like so:
List<Flyer> fliers = Arrays.asList(new Airplane(), new Bird());
```

They also allow Objects to fit into several different boxes.  For example, a `Bird` not only flies, but it is an `Animal`.  Interfaces allow you to treat `Bird` as either one:

```
public interface Animal {
  public void move();
}

public class Bird implements Flyer, Animal {
  @Override
  public void fly() {
    System.out.println("I'm flying");
  }   

  @Override
  public void move() {
    fly();
  }
}

// now I can do:
Bird bird = new Bird();
Flyer flyer = new Bird();
Animal animal = new Bird();
```

***Decoupled Design***

Additionally, they give you flexibility in choosing your implementation.  (I'm not sure what you mean by "Standardizing the Expectation", but this use is probably *most* related to standardization.  i.e. This works *because* it creates a standard.) For example, say I have a method that returns a `List<Flyer>`.  Since `List` is an interface, I can choose use `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc. as my implementation:

```
public List<Flyer> makeFlyerList() {
  return new ArrayList<Flyer>(Arrays.asList(new Airplane(), new Bird()));
}

// works just the same
public List<Flyer> makeFlyerList() {
  return new LinkedList<Flyer>(Arrays.asList(new Airplane(), new Bird()));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces are a way to declare a contract for implementing classes to fulfill; it's the primary tool to create **abstraction** and **decoupled designs** between consumers and producers.

Comment: Can you help me to understand regarding decoupled design.

Comment: @Jagdeep It allows you to change implementations with no side effects.  See my answer for a short example of this.

Answer (score 3):

One other case that comes in my mind is the marker functionality.

`java.lang.Cloneable` for example, doesn't have any method declaration, it is used just to flag the class that implements as a clonable class.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html):

> A class implements the Cloneable interface to indicate to the
>   Object.clone() method that it is legal for that method to make a
>   field-for-field copy of instances of that class.

Another sample of the same use could be seen in [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Comment: That's a deprecated usage of interfaces. Since Java 1.6 annotations are the way to do that.

Comment: what  I understand from your answer is that : even clonable interface help you to expect that Object.Clone() can implement the clone method
which could have been flagged any other way as well.

Comment: @kay: using marker interfaces provides compile time type checking whereas annotations can only be checked via runtime reflection - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995198/what-is-the-use-of-marker-interfaces-in-java/5080547#5080547

Answer (score 0):

Java has a limitation by design in the Inheritance(i.e. Multiple Inheritance). 
So you can not extend more than one class but you can implement as many interfaces as you want.

Second advantage of using interfaces in java is related to the design and performance of the application. For any application it is required to be "loosely coupled" and "highly coherent".
Here interfaces come into the picture. Interfaces implement the contract between the classes and hence design becomes the loosely coupled.

Hope this will be helpfull.

Comment: But interface does not give any code to support multiple inheritance. In the class itself you have to implement the method so as per I think there is nothing that interface helps in multiple Inheritance. Without implementing inheritance you can directly write the code in the class.

Comment: "I think there is nothing that interface helps in multiple inheritance"

Java interfaces enable a kind of multiple inheritance in the language, which otherwise doesn't support it at all.  It is true you cannot inherit code from multiple classes, but you can inherit their method signatures, and that allows an object to implement collections of method signatures defined in different places.

Comment: I would like you to notice one thing in java. "Everything in java is an Object(at some extent)". So it is not possible to extend to Classes as methods in the Object does not resolve at run time. This is the on of the reasons why interfaces are designed in java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I would object to the word 'just'.

Remember that you can define not only abstract methods but all sorts of other baggage that comes with the `expectation`.

For example, notice that in the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface there is the [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) inner interface. Here we see not only *what you can expect of a Map* but a good deal of detail about some of the things you can expect **from** a `Map` such as their `Entries`.

Although you won't find many examples in the java API there are many cases in real-world programming where you will have large numbers of `enum`s and/or `public static final`s in an interface class too. These are used to refine and detail, almost to an excessive level, what you can and cannot do to objects of this type.

In summary, you are correct ... to an extent ... that an `interface` is merely *standardizing the expectation* but a little research will show you that *standardizing the expectation* is a wide and deep subject worthy of some incredibly complex `interface`s.